# Login as non-admin user removes Dashboard submenu. I wish to re-enable it

Tags: dashboard

Ideally, since the "Dashboard" submenu is gone for authors, I just want to replace it with a single link that pulls up the wp-admin home page.

Just re-enabling Dashboard>home would work well too.

[edit]
Here is what I have now.  I know this isn't the best way to do this, but I couldn't get "add_menu_page" do do it correctly.  I manually edited the $menu variable.

This will work as a solution if I cannot find a better way.

```
add_action( 'admin_menu', function (){
    if ( !current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) {
        global $menu;
        $menu[0]=[
            0 => 'Dashboard',
            1 => 'read',
            2 => 'index.php',
            3 => '',
            4 => 'menu-top menu-top-first menu-icon-dashboard',
            5 => 'menu-dashboard',
            6 => 'dashicons-dashboard',
        ];
    }
});
```

Comment: I located where the theme author removed the menu via remove_menu_page()

Answer (score 1):

It's not the menu you need to adjust - it's your roles and capabilities.

By default, a WP Core Author has "Dashboard" in their menu. You're correct, they do not have a submenu under Dashboard, but clicking Dashboard takes them to the same page as "Dashboard > Home" for other users.

You may want to look through whatever plugins you're using that may have adjusted permissions, and/or use a user role plugin to check what permissions users have. If they can't see "Dashboard" at all, they need "read" capability added:

```
// hook to admin init
add_action('admin_init', 'add_author_caps');
function add_author_caps() {
    // get the author role
    $role = get_role('author');
    // add "read" capability
    $role->add_cap('read');
}
```

You can add this temporarily wherever you like - theme or plugin - and after you've logged in and viewed anything in wp-admin, you can remove this code as WP will save the capability.

Comment: Author's on this site, already have read capabilities

Comment: It wasn't the roles that were incorrect.  I located where the theme author removed the menu via remove_menu_page()